# Unable to generate a model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I simply can't generate a model in Rails 4:

```
rails g model m1 a b
```

And there is nothing appears in `db` and `app/model` directories. And there is no error in the terminal either.

Comment: restart you computer, if that doesn't help provide your `database.yml` file

Comment: Did you create the database with 'rake db:create' ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does any other generator work? For example `rails g migration test_rails`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the database

```
rake db:create
```